# Change UIButton image to another one objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, image, uibutton

I want to change an image on my UIButton when a user presses on it. The image has transparency effects (it is a .png that shows only an edge). The problem is that when the button is tapped, all works fine (other functions connected to it), but the app overwrites the 2 different images one over the second! When the button is pressed I want to show the second image, and remove the first (that becomes unnecessary). PS: I don't want to use array of images. Here the code for the button:

```
UIButton *overlayButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[overlayButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[overlayButton setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 382, 120, 60)];
[overlayButton addTarget:self action:@selector(scanButtonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; //just graphics
[overlayButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonshapeClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; //just to set a variable i++ for my cycle
[overlayButton addTarget:self action:@selector(changeshape:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];  //function that changes another shape
[[self view] addSubview:overlayButton];
```

my simple cycle

```
- (void)buttonshapeClicked:(id)sender{
shape++;
if (shape == 4) {
    shape = 1;
        }}
```

here the main function that allows to change a primary shape on the screen

```
 -(void) changeshape:(id)sender {
if (shape==1 && people==2) {
    //bottone forma
    UIButton *overlayButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [overlayButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"passaquadrato.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [overlayButton setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 382, 120, 60)];
    [overlayButton addTarget:self action:@selector(scanButtonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [overlayButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonshapeClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [overlayButton addTarget:self action:@selector(changeshape:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [[self view] addSubview:overlayButton];

    //bottone people
    UIButton *overlayButtonp = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [overlayButtonp setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"passatre.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [overlayButtonp setFrame:CGRectMake(180, 382, 120, 60)];
    [overlayButtonp addTarget:self action:@selector(scanButtonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [[self view] addSubview:overlayButtonp];

    UIImageView *overlayImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"circle2.png"]];
    [overlayImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 88, 280, 280)];
    [[self view] addSubview:overlayImageView];
}


else if (shape==2 && people==2) {
    //bottone forma
    UIButton *overlayButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [overlayButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"passarettangolo.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [overlayButton setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 382, 120, 60)];
    [overlayButton addTarget:self action:@selector(scanButtonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [overlayButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonshapeClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [overlayButton addTarget:self action:@selector(changeshape:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [[self view] addSubview:overlayButton];

    //bottone people
    UIButton *overlayButtonp = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [overlayButtonp setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"passatre.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [overlayButtonp setFrame:CGRectMake(180, 382, 120, 60)];
    [overlayButtonp addTarget:self action:@selector(scanButtonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [[self view] addSubview:overlayButtonp];

    UIImageView *overlayImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"square2.png"]];
    [overlayImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 88, 280, 280)];
    [[self view] addSubview:overlayImageView];
}}
```

I want to have the same button but with a different image to show

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you are ever removing the previous buttons.

Also, you don't have to create new buttons - you can simply store a reference to the button, and *change* the image, and *change* the action target (by removing the old ones before adding the new ones).

Comment: Yes is something that I've tryed! So, now I've written a method that eliminate everything from the view to clear all. I know that isn't the best solution, but it is a solution. :) Now the problem is that it doesn't work when I try to re-inititialize the cycle, because I've another problem of overviewing!

Comment: You'll have to explain a bit more in what you mean by 'problem of overviewing' before I can help. Details are important.

Comment: The problem is that, when I try to reinitialize my variable, I rehave the same problem That I've solved. Here the method to reinitialize my variable. Is it correct?    - (void)buttonshapeClicked:(id)sender
{
 //PROBLEMA DOPO UN CICLO COMPLETO
    shape++;
    if (shape == 4) {
        shape = 1;
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

I've solved for a few of cycle with removing all from the view with:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [[self.view subviews] count]; i++ ) {
        [[[self.view subviews] objectAtIndex:i] removeFromSuperview];
    }
```

The problem now is to reinitialize the cycle because, when my variable goes to 4 I want that it becomes 1. I do it with:

```
- (void)buttonshapeClicked:(id)sender{shape++;
if (shape == 4) {
    shape = 1;
}}
```

But after the number 4, I've the same problem of overview that I've had before!